# MySQL: query optimization - how to store query result in variable

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I've got tables user, event (public, private or secret type), attendant, organizer and I need to select all events where user 1 is attendant OR organizer EXCEPT secret events, where user 2 IS NOT (attending OR organizer OR invited).

This huge SELECT does all I need but it consists of many other SELECTs. **Is it somehow possible to optimize it Like put that union bordered by comments FROM HERE - TO HERE to some kind of variable and re-use it?**

**EDIT: I need to be able to do more of those requests at the time.**

```
SELECT `event`.id AS eventid, event.name AS ename
FROM attendant
INNER JOIN user ON attendant.fk_user = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON attendant.fk_event = `event`.id
WHERE user.id = 2
AND attendant.fk_event = `event`.id
AND `event`.id IN
-- FROM HERE
(
SELECT `event`.id
FROM attendant
INNER JOIN user ON attendant.fk_user = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON attendant.fk_event = `event`.id
WHERE user.id = 1
AND attendant.fk_event = `event`.id

UNION

SELECT `event`.id
FROM organizer
INNER JOIN user ON organizer.fk_user = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON organizer.fk_event = event.id
WHERE user.id = 1
AND organizer.fk_event = event.id

UNION

SELECT `event`.id
FROM invitation
INNER JOIN user ON invitation.fk_user_to = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON invitation.fk_event = event.id
WHERE invitation.fk_user_to = 1
AND invitation.fk_event = event.id)
-- TO HERE

UNION

SELECT `event`.id AS eventid, event.name AS ename
FROM organizer
INNER JOIN user ON organizer.fk_user = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON organizer.fk_event = event.id
WHERE user.id = 2
AND organizer.fk_event = event.id
AND `event`.id IN
(
-- FROM HERE
SELECT `event`.id
FROM attendant
INNER JOIN user ON attendant.fk_user = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON attendant.fk_event = `event`.id
WHERE user.id = 1
AND attendant.fk_event = `event`.id

UNION

SELECT `event`.id
FROM organizer
INNER JOIN user ON organizer.fk_user = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON organizer.fk_event = event.id
WHERE user.id = 1
AND organizer.fk_event = event.id

UNION

SELECT `event`.id
FROM invitation
INNER JOIN user ON invitation.fk_user_to = user.id
INNER JOIN event ON invitation.fk_event = event.id
WHERE invitation.fk_user_to = 1
AND invitation.fk_event = event.id);
-- TO HERE
```

Comment: If it functions, this should probably go on CodeReview or so...

Comment: @user2366842 I'm rather searching for tips, how to store query result in some kind of "variable" (I know it's not possible with normal variable), that's why I've used this site.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create views to get the intermediate results and reuse them.

Views are cheap: the data is not stored and you can use them in select.

In your case as a small example:

`` create view viewname_1 as SELECT event.id
    FROM invitation
    INNER JOIN user ON invitation.fk_user_to = user.id
    INNER JOIN event ON invitation.fk_event = event.id
    WHERE invitation.fk_user_to = 1
    AND invitation.fk_event = event.id
    AND
    (event.type = 'secret'
    OR event.type = 'private'
    OR event.type = 'public')
    )` ``

and later on use viewname_1 as select * from viewname_1...

Obviously, you can choose your own naming convention for views: just be careful with the namespaces.

Comment: I found out this is not exactly what I need. When I create a View and use it, another request can rewrite it and compromise my query.

Comment: Hold on: you're supposed to create the views only once. Could you please post the whole SQL?

Comment: I think I shouldn't post the whole 1000-line SQL. :) I need to get this result before every query to database and then work with it. Any ideas please?

Comment: The result for querying a view is not stored. It's live content. If you  make a select based on joins of views, your query is not compromised. I can help more if I can get a live example. It doesn't need to be posted here

Comment: Please see my edited question again, mainly the bold parts and the code. Also database is created with http://pastebin.com/LWW2uSe1 and some CONSTRAINTs. I Hope it helps for understanding the question.

Comment: table invitation is missing from your pastebin... do you have some sample data? it would help debugging the query...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it there. With invitation - http://pastebin.com/NJtWfvgt. Sample data would not work for this, because it's not complete code with CONSTRAINTS and all tables.